# 404 permalink errors on Pages only

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, 404-error

I am having a strange issue with permalinks while using the `/%postname%/` structure.

I can access my custom post types using the pretty permalink `localhost/cpu/<post-type>/<post-title>/` but I am getting a 404 error on Pages. The url of a page is `localhost/cpu/<page-title>/`

My `.htaccess` file (generated automatically when saving permalinks):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cpu/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /cpu/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My WordPress(version 3.4.2) installation is in a folder called `cpu`. I don't have any issues with the default permalink structure `url/?p=123`. The problem does not go away when I disable all plugins.

Any possible solution?

Is there a way to debug what's happening?

**UPDATE:**

Following *Code Monkey*'s answer, I added the following to functions.php
I changed the filter from `rewrite_rules_array` to `page_rewrite_rules` - the [WP_Rewrite Class reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) suggests:

> To filter the rewrite rules generated for your Pages, use
>   page_rewrite_rules.

So, here's the code I added:

```
add_filter('page_rewrite_rules', 'rewrite_rules_array_filter_debug', 10000);

function rewrite_rules_array_filter_debug($rules){
  echo '<pre>';  
  var_dump($rules);
  echo '</pre>';
  return $rules;
}
```

And the output from saving the post permalinks on `wp-admin/options-permalink.php`:

```
array(11) {
  [".?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/?$"]=>
  string(32) "index.php?attachment=$matches[1]"
  [".?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$"]=>
  string(37) "index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1"
  [".?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"]=>
  string(49) "index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]"
  [".?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"]=>
  string(49) "index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]"
  [".?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$"]=>
  string(50) "index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]"
  ["(.?.+?)/trackback/?$"]=>
  string(35) "index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&tb=1"
  ["(.?.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"]=>
  string(47) "index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]"
  ["(.?.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"]=>
  string(47) "index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]"
  ["(.?.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$"]=>
  string(48) "index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]"
  ["(.?.+?)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$"]=>
  string(48) "index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]"
  ["(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$"]=>
  string(47) "index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]"
}
```

Anything wrong in it?

**UPDATE 2:**

I found my error when using `var_dump($wp);`.

I got this response:

```
  ["query_string"]=>
  string(25) "statut-membre=sample-page"
  ["request"]=>
  string(11) "sample-page"
  ["matched_rule"]=>
  string(10) "([^/]+)/?$"
  ["matched_query"]=>
  string(25) "statut-membre=sample-page"
  ["did_permalink"]=>
  bool(true)
```

Wordpress was querying a taxonomy called `statut-membre` while looking for my pages. I noticed I had an empty rewrite slug(`'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),`)  in that `register_taxonomy` function. I added a slug and resaved my permalink structure, now my I can access my pages.

Now the query looks fine too:

```
  ["query_string"]=>
  string(20) "pagename=sample-page"
  ["request"]=>
  string(11) "sample-page"
  ["matched_rule"]=>
  string(20) "(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$"
  ["matched_query"]=>
  string(26) "pagename=sample-page&page="
  ["did_permalink"]=>
  bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try replace

```
RewriteRule . /cpu/index.php [L]
```

by

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

as for a way to debug...

well you can always var_dump a $wp_query object to get an idea what variables not passed to wp. (you can place  ) into first line of your header.php template.

and i belive next step will be debug of rewrites in this case usefull filter is **rewrites_array_rules** which you can use for debug proposes in a next way

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'rewrite_rules_array_filter_debug', 10000);
    function rewrite_rules_array_filter_debug($rules){
    var_dump($rules);
    return $rules;
}
```

add this to header php

```
   <?php 
          global $wp;
          echo '<pre>';
          var_dump($wp);
          echo '</pre>';
   ?>
```

this shoudl give you a point what rewrite rulle trigger to you page request.

Comment: I get redirected to `localhost/xampp` after rewriting the `.htaccess` as you suggested. I reverted back to my initial configuration. I'm trying your function, but I'm not getting any output right now.

Comment: Oh it the filter upon saving `wp-admin/options-permalink.php`? I'm updating my question with the results.

Comment: one more debug code added.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to tell apache to follow your .htaccess file. You can do this by editing the apache.conf file

```
$sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache.conf
```

Scroll down to the line 
By default it will be:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

change the value of AllowOverride to All so now it becomes:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Press ctrl+x and press y to save the configuration file. In order to make this changes to server first enable the mod_rewrite by.

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And then restart the server

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Done!

Source: https://www.wst.space/riddling-with-wordpress-permalink-setup-issues/

Comment: I missed this while setting up my server, finally found the culprit. Good catch